# Using PHP variable as autocomplete source

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've simplified the problem down as much as possible, I feel like this should work. The below script controls the autocomplete function and works as expected (if a user types 't', 'test' appears as a suggested input).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var availableClients = ['test'];
    $("#addClient").autocomplete({
        source: availableClients,
    });
});
</script>
```

However, if I set a PHP variable $test = "'test'" and replace 'test' in the original script with `<?php echo $test; ?>` the autocomplete script no longer works. Is there another way I can use a PHP variable as the autocomplete source or am I missing something?

EDIT: Here is the script with the PHP in it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var availableClients = [<?php echo $test; ?>];
    $("#addClient").autocomplete({
        source: availableClients,
    });
});
</script>
```

And the only relevant PHP code is this.

```
$test = "'test'";
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with this, you probably need to show us more code.

Comment: Please include the full PHP code where you're trying to insert `$test` as well as the output it generates.

Comment: Added all relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is probably that you aren't including the quotes when echoing the value of the variable. Try this:

```
var availableClients = ['<?php echo $test; ?>'];
```

As it turns out, the issue was actually that you were not defining `$test` before you were `echo`ing it. This:

```
$test = "'test'";
```

needs to occur *before* this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var availableClients = [<?php echo $test; ?>];
    $("#addClient").autocomplete({
        source: availableClients,
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Or of course `<?=$test?>` if you have [short open tags enabled](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). Make sure that the js file ends with `.php` or is interpreted as a PHP file so it executes the PHP.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yeah, but those are deprecated if I remember correctly.

Comment: (I can't @ you for some reason) According to my link: `This directive also affected the shorthand <?= before PHP 5.4.0, which is identical to <? echo. Use of this shortcut required short_open_tag to be on. Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available.` - so it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Asad - hard to tell but the $test variable is 'test', the quotes are already there.

Comment: @h2ooooooo You're right, although I could swear I read that in an article somewhere. I suppose the disadvantage is that your code isn't portable to servers where short tags are disabled.

Comment: @scrolls Whoops, mistook you for someone else. Could you please post the code where you are setting the value for `$test`? Also, give this a whirl and see if it works.

Comment: @scrolls I can't spot anything wrong. Could you please add the entire php page source to a pastebin and give me the link?

Comment: easy to look in source view in browser or in console and see what actually arrives at page

Comment: @scrolls You are otputting `$test` before you have defined it. The part where you do this: `$test = "'test'";` needs to come before the part where you do this: `<?php echo $test; ?>`